# Joomla Configuration File writing issue with Ubuntu 16.04 and nginx

Tags: server, permissions, php, nginx, joomla

I keep getting errors from joomla saying it can't write to.

```
configuration.php
An error has occurred.
0 Could not write to the configuration file
```

I added recommended permissions to folders 755 and files 644
with no luck.

I am using root to log into so not sure what login Joomla is using to write to a file

/var/www/websitecom.com/html

```
line on var/www/mywebsite.com/html folder
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root     4096 Oct 11 21:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Oct 11 17:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     3005 Aug 26 07:59 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    18092 Aug 26 07:59 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     4883 Aug 26 07:59 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root     4096 Sep 10 18:23 administrator
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 10 18:23 bin
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     4096 Oct  8 17:43 cache
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 10 18:39 cli
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 Oct  5 18:57 components
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     3342 Oct 12 12:13 configuration.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      974 Oct  8 17:50 favicon-16x16.png
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     1810 Oct  8 17:50 favicon-32x32.png
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    15086 Oct  8 17:50 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 79731414 Oct 11 18:10 food.zip
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root     4096 Oct  5 17:45 images
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 39626638 Oct  8 18:12 images.zip
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Sep 10 18:23 includes
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      182 Oct 11 21:47 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     1420 Aug 26 07:59 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Sep 10 18:23 language
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Sep 10 18:23 layouts
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root     4096 Oct  5 11:31 libraries
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Oct 12 13:12 logs
drwxr-xr-x 38 root root     4096 Oct  5 18:59 media
drwxr-xr-x 33 root root     4096 Oct  5 18:58 modules
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root     4096 Oct  5 18:59 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      842 Oct  1  2014 robots.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      836 Aug 26 07:59 robots.txt.dist
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     4096 Sep 10 18:23 templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Oct 12 13:12 tmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     1690 Aug 26 07:59 web.config.txt
```

Premissions for the html folder

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 11 17:48 .
drwxr-xr-x: command not found
root@pitamyshawarma:~# drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Oct 11 17:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x: command not found
root@pitamyshawarma:~# drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Oct 11 21:47 html
drwxr-xr-x: command not found
```

Comment: It sometimes has to do with root file ownership.  What's the permissions on `/var/www/websitecom.com/html`?  YOu can get us this information by doing `ls -al /var/www/websitecom.com/` and showing us the line with the `html` folder.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Oct 11 17:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Oct 11 17:32 ..
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Oct 11 21:47 html

Comment: Hi Thomas  thanks for taking a look attaching the folder info to the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NGINX web server runs as the user `www-data` and the group `www-data` by default on Ubuntu systems.  (So does Apache2 but that's not necessarily relevant to this question)  And the default configuration of PHP also has such setup to use the `www-data` user/group as well.

The typical way to set up your website 'directory' and files is to set the user ownership to `root` (or your own user), and the group ownership to `www-data` and provide the `www-data` group with read/write.

We can do this with only a few commands:

1. Change user/group ownership for all files and folders to `root:www-data`.

   ```
   sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/websitecom.com/html
   ```
2. Set proper permissions for directories and folders.

   Folders: 775 (`rwxrwxr-x`) - allow owner access and group members read/write access to folders, and allow 'other users' to traverse the directory tree

   ```
   sudo find /var/www/websitecom.com/html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`
   ```

   Files: 660 (`rw-rw----`) - allow owner access and group members read/write access to files, disallow all other users access to the files themselves.

   ```
   sudo find /var/www/websitecom.com/html -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;`
   ```
3. Set the `setgid` bit on the directories.  This way, when files are created by either `root` or the web server, the 'group' ownership of new files will remain `www-data`.

   ```
   sudo find /var/www/websitecom.com/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
   ```
4. Make sure the docroot actually has the proper permissions.

   ```
   sudo chmod 770 /var/www/websitecom.com/html
   sudo chmod g+s /var/www/websitecom.com/html
   ```

Now, your webserver should be able to write to the new configuration file.